# Slack integration for Firebase Crashlytics isn't working

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, slack

I have a slack channel where some apps report crashes on crashlytics. They are working fine. However, I am setting up a new app, with the same configuration that worked before, and it is not working. Crashes are reported fine on the web console, but these crashes aren't reaching the slack channel.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Same issue for me also.